# Does a dual-casting prestige class exist in D&D 3.0?

Tags: dnd-3e, prestige-class

Are there any prestige classes the same as or similar to Mystic Theurge before the 3.5 update?

I would consider a class fundamentally the same if it fully advanced both arcane and divine casting, and similar if it fully/mostly advanced both. I would not consider something like the *Tome & Blood* True Necromancer similar for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in fact if you look back at the chatter from the earliest previews of the mystic theurge, for example in letters to the editor at *Dragon* if I recall correctly, the class generated a lot of talk and (naive) concern about balance, since such a thing had not been seen before.

Comment: Whether it's is naive or not is a matter of what you compare it to. It is certainly unbalanced compared to 'normal' divine/arcane caster hybrids!

Comment: Indeed it did create a lot of controversy at the time. [Here on the Wizards Archive](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dd/20060616a)  the original author himself wrote, briefly, about it.

Comment: @WeckarE. Exactly—that is a naive comparison to make.